# expressjs sessions not working across subdomains

Tags: node.js, session, express

I'm using sessions in express and have it setup as:

```
app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore(),
  secret : '',
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    domain: '.localdomain.com'
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

I then have `localdomain.com` in my hosts as well as `test.localdomain.com`, when I access routes via `test.localdomain.com` I'm able to get session data, however when I make an ajax request to `localdomain.com`, this doesn't have the sessions available.  For example, on `test.localdomain.com`, I'll make a request:

`$.get('http://localdomain.com/session')` and the session is there, but none of the values I've set to session are returned.

Any ideas how I can access sessions?

Answer (score -1):

fron the express session source code it seems it uses indexOf which does not allow a regex so regex and array are not an option,

```
// pathname mismatch
var originalPath = parseUrl.original(req).pathname;
if (originalPath.indexOf(cookieOptions.path || '/') !== 0) return next();
```

IMHO, the best option would be to write your own session or use tokens, hope I helped. :)